# Purpose of BAL in 3 tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a newbie for 3 tier architecture as it consists of UI,BAL and DAL layers.So i am writing all the database code in DAL and i have declaring the variables in BAL and i have calling the methods into the UI,but is this is the correct way to code??What is my BAL is doing then?what is the main purpose of business layer?Can anyone explain me,Thanks.

```
 //In my BAL



public class ProfileMasterBLL
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FormFiledBy { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

//In my UI

```
 ProfileMasterBLL pmBLL = new ProfileMasterBLL();
        pmBLL.FirstName = TextBox1.Text;
        pmBLL.LastName = TextBox2.Text;



//In my DAL
```

method for insert()

then how can i call ProfileMasterBLL.insert() ?? as i have written in DAL.

Comment: How much logic a system must contain, and where it contains is naturally dependent on what the system does. It would be a little easier to comment on this if you could give us a short description of what you are creating. That way we could provide answers that may be more in the context you are interested in.

Comment: Your edit is not an example of a three tier architecture.  You have what appears to be an ADT (an abstract data type) you should create a seperate class for these types of packages.  You then can use that ADT to pass around in your BL and DAL.  Properties should really not exist for a Business Logic Layer, at most should just be simple methods to call the DAL.

Comment: When i have searched in google i got different types of results for 3 tier architecture,everybody having their own way of implementing it so really i am somewhat confused.If you found any good examples pls post it here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Business Layer is used as the middle man between your UI and the DAL.
It is used for any or all business logic that your application will encompass.  For example, in an accounting application you may want to perform some calculations and checks on the data before you send it off to the database layer, you would perform this in the business layer.

Your UI could do something like so:

```
//establish person object
//pass in some salary with it to BL
BL.CalcPay(somePerson, someSalary);
```

Then in your BL:

```
//inside of BL
//if its a CEO they are lucky, they get paid twice as much
 decimal toGive = someSalary;
if(somePerson.IsCEO)
 toGive = toGive * 2; //CEO gets paid more :(

//now call DAL
DAL.CalcPay(somePerson, toGive)
```

Then in your DAL:

```
//inside of DAL
//perform some update by calling for instance a sproc
using(SQL....)
{
}
```

Not the best of examples but it should get the point across, there are many times where your BL doesn't do anything but hand off a method call to the DAL.  Just because it is the BL doesn't mean it has to have some sort of check associated with it.  So you may end up doing something like this:

```
//inside UI
string s = BL.GetSomeString();

//inside BL
return DAL.GetSomeSomeString();

//inside DAL
return someString;
```

Comment: Is it appropriate to call a method directly from DAL to UI??So what is business logic means?what to code there?

Comment: No your User Interface should not know about the Data Access Layer, in fact your ui should not include any type of sql reference, such as sql data readers.  Read the edit I made, your UI sends some info to the BL, the BL may perform logic on the data and then and only then if the logic is ok it sends it to the DAL.  The DAL performs an operation on the data and submits some sort of status or a result back to the BL.  The BL takes the information from the DAL and delivers it to the UI.

Comment: //In my BAL  

 public class ProfileMasterBLL
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FormFiledBy { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}

//In my UI

ProfileMasterBLL pmBLL = new ProfileMasterBLL();
 pmBLL.FirstName = TextBox1.Text;
 pmBLL.LastName =TextBox2.Text;

//In my DAL

method for insert()

is this the correct way of doing?

Comment: I dont understand what you are doing and you really do not need to instantiate your BL class, its a single repository that calls the data access layer, therefore it should be static and it would be called like this `//from ui BL.InsertUser(myUser);` no need to do a `BusinessLayer bl = new BusinessLayer(); //unnecessary` its simply a static class.  Edit your question and add your code and use the markup so we can understand what you are asking.

Comment: Then how to call the insert method into BLL??what is (myuser) here? how to use the mark up? sorry im a newbie to this forum...

Comment: You call the method using the class name dot method.  `BL.InsertUser(...)`

Comment: but i have written the method in the DAL so i cant access it from the BAL...so i can't call like this BL.Insert

Comment: the BL calls the DAL.  So inside your BL you would do `DAL.Insert(...)` where DAL is a static data access layer class.

Comment: So i have to create a new class for it or can i use the same ProfileMasterBLL class for this as shown above?if i have several methods can i call them in the same class?

Comment: Of course that is the whole point of 3-tier-architecture each tier is its own class.  The UI is composed of multiple classes, the BLL is one class (static), the DAL is one class (also static).  The ui calls the BLL which in turn calls the DAL.  The DAL processes information and returns the result to the BL which presents it to the UI.  It looks like this UI->BL->DAL which then becomes DAL->BL->UI.  It is a fairly simple architecture, I recommend googling it.

Comment: Last question ;) so shall i create a new class for every method?or one class for all the methods in BAL?beside this what are the other uses of BAL?

Thanks for answering my questions patiently :)

Comment: Chandra I am trying to assist you more but it becomes difficult to do via comments.  I tried to open a chat directly on this site with you but it appears "you do not have enough rep".  That isn't nice to you or to me so I posted it on meta and hopefully someone can see my point and how frustrating it has become to just help someone.  I cant believe having "rep" would entitle someone to get more help it doesn't make sense.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142069/please-avoid-discussion-go-to-chat

Comment: Its not a bal its a bl and a dal.  Dal is data layer, bl is business layer.  2 seperate classes each has its own methods, in many cases the method signatures match.

Comment: Now i am creating classes in BAL and calling methods from DAL and using them in UI....i think this is the right way.

Comment: Your ui should not interact with your DAL at all.

Comment: So i have to create classes for methods in DAL and i have to use them in UI is it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

The role of Business Layer is to execute business rule, for example validation of your entities, execution of business rules on the entities, execution of business function on entities.

often you have two choices.

Implement business logic in stored procedures

or

Implement business logic in the business layers

Comment: Implementing business logic in stored procedures is an anti-pattern and should definitely be avoided.

Comment: No i don't think because in functional context very hard, it's impossible to load all entities in your context even with lazyloading

Comment: you can not tell the experts database that stored procedure is an anti pattern

Comment: I didn't say stored procs are an anti-pattern.  I said business logic in stored procs is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The business layer exists to provide a place to put your business logic.  Data access logic should do nothing but create, retrieve, update, and delete (CRUD) operations against your database.  The presentation layer should have nothing but the logic that determines how your user interacts with the system.

For example, if you click "add user" in your UI, this could call an BAL.AddUser() method in your business layer that would then call multiple data layer methods, such as DAL.AddUser() to insert the User, then DAL.AddUserToGroup() to put the new user in a default group.

Comment: That example might not be the best as your BOL can actually call DAL.AddUser and your DAL can do something to the effect of `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Login = @Login) RETURN -1 ELSE BEGIN INSERT INTO Users...RETURN @SCOPE_IDENTITY END` and handle the check if the user exists or not.  The status is sent back in the form of an integer.  That integer is passed from the DAL to the BOL and the BOL presents it back to the UI, the UI can then throw up a message.

Comment: @rs_atl yeah but there what is my BAL is doing?Is it good to call a method from DAL to UI directly?I am some what confused....

Comment: @Chandrasekhar - no you do not call the UI from the DAL, they don't concern themselves with each other and it does not make sense to call the UI from the DAL.

Comment: @JonH Of course that is possible.  I was simply trying to illustrate that a business layer call may call multiple data layer methods--or even other business layer methods.  Your statement also presumes a lot about the underlying database.

Comment: @rs_atl - database vendor doesn't matter, they all have some form of what I posted.

Comment: @JonH Not true.  Mine does not.

Comment: @JonH However your point that such logic can exist in the DAL is valid. I'm splitting hairs... :)

Comment: I have updated my post to remove the reference to the offending method call.